# How to disable Nouvea before Linux boots

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I am trying to install the proprietary Nvidia driver on my linux machine ( Nvidia GeForce GTX 750, Debian w/Linux 4.1.2.1 ).  In order to use Nvidia's `.run` file, I need to disable nouveau.  The `.run` creates a file that will do this task, but a reboot is required.  However, disabling nouveau has broken the boot cycle.  What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Did you try to boot into text mode? See here for example: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15527/how-to-boot-debian-into-text-mode-without-using-gui

Comment: yes, and .run still says nouveau is in use ( and it is correct )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newer Linux kernals are given the job of setting video modes ( [archlinux.org...](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_mode_setting) ) and as such, Nouveau is being used at boot time ( even without an X server ).

In order to disable Nouveau **and boot** use the argument `nomodeset` in your Grub configuration. [ubuntuforums.org...](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)

Answer (score 4):

Adding `nouveau.blacklist=1` on the linux line might help, or...

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf
# generated by nvidia-installer
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

The linux line is what I have seen earlier, that has obviously changed...
the '...disable-nouveau.conf' file is what there is now.

Oh, if you try to install the driver from the Text login (CTRL-ALT-F1) then you need to `sudo -i` and then do

```
stop lightdm # or whatever window manager you have
init 3
```

before you attempt to install/uninstall.

---

For what it is worth:
*I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.2, 3.16 kernel, with a GTX 780, v352.30 proprietary driver*

I normally boot into rescue mode to remedy problems with the driver,  lately that has most often been as simple as
`bash NVIDIA...run --uninstall` immediately followed by a
`bash NVIDIA...run`
and necessary only as some sort of graphics system component, or kernel, has been updated.

Comment: ```nouveau.blacklist=1``` --> unknown parameter 'blacklist' ...ignored

Comment: I've solved my problem and then asked the question a little better ( I hope ).  I also supplied an answer ( which I apparently have to wait a while before accepting :) ).  Thanks

Comment: =) - I'll leave this as is, maybe someone else finds it useful.